# Encrypt/Decrypt column in sql server using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption, ssms

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt some columns in SQL database using Entity Framework 6 and database project.

I created my master key:

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY [CMK_1]
WITH
(
    KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE',
    KEY_PATH = N'CurrentUser/my/D4331582F1485517DA1807CF0A5500C........'
)
```

and my encryption key:

```
CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY [CEK_1]
WITH VALUES
(
     COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = [CMK_1],
     ALGORITHM = N'RSA_OAEP',
     ENCRYPTED_VALUE = 0x016E00000163007500....
);
```

and mt table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyWords]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [MyWord] [NVARCHAR](4) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH(ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_1]) NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

The database is created successfully. Both the table and the keys exist.

I am trying to add a new entry to the database using entity framework but I am getting this error:

> Failed to decrypt a column cipher key using the following key store
>   provider: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the
>   encrypted column encryption key are: 'AF-B3-97-27-5A-BC-33-24-75-FA'.
>   \ R \ nDegumental certificate
>   'D4331582F1485517DA1807C.....' was not in the 'My'
>   certificate store under the location 'CurrentUser' found.

I don't know why.

P.S. I added the enable parameter in the connection string:

> Column Encryption Setting = Enabled;

Am I missing something here? Why do I receive this error on .SaveChanges?
a little explanation would be very helpful!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After two days of searching, I found the answer. The problem was with not knowing the certificate. So I generated the certificate using Always Encrypted:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37979.working-with-the-always-encrypted-feature-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

and then I went to certificate manager and copied the fingerprint of the generated certificate and paste it when generating the master key:

> KEY_PATH = N'CurrentUser/my/[new_fingerprint]'

and it works. It will always be encrypted on my local machine. I tried to back up the database and use it on another machine. the column was encrypted until I export/import the certificate.